# Adjective or adverb describing promotion of self or group one belongs to

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, adverbs

Is there an adjective or adverb depicting self-promotion (or promotion of a group one belongs to)?

I am thinking of something that has a somewhat negative connotation, in the spirit of phrases

- patting yourself on the back
- shameless self-plug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person who engages in shameless self-promotion is [*self-aggrandizing*](http://www.wordnik.com/words/self-aggrandizing).

Merriam-Webster's pithy definition:

> **self-aggrandizing**, *adjective*: acting or seeking to make oneself greater.

Comment: This was my first thought. I was working on an answer suggesting it, but was researching further after this, _**self-ag·gran·dize·ment** n.The act or practice of enhancing or exaggerating one's own importance, power, or reputation_ (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-aggrandizing) gave me pause. I wondered if self-promotion was necessarily enhancement or exaggeration, but found other definitions, such this, _the action of promoting oneself as being powerful or important_, which seem to make my hesitation moot. So, +1 for **self-aggrandizing**.

Comment: Yeah, I've second-guessed myself out of answering more than once. (Almost daily, come to think of it.)

Answer (score 1):

*[Exhibitionism](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/exhibitionism)* (noun) is behaviour to make people notice you and is usually used with a negative connotation.

Answer (score 0):

Several self-promotion verbs (*pitch, [tout](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tout), vaunt, pimp*) can be used as adjectives when given *-ed* suffixes; for example:

> I joined the much-touted club.

The meaning seems to be clear and correct; however, although *much touted* has seen [some usage over the years](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much-touted%2Cmuch+touted&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3), *much-touted* has not:[image: much-touted]
The frequency of use of *touted* by itself is a few dozen times higher than that of *much touted*.

Also consider adjective *ostentatious*, which often refers to pretentious self-promotion intended to attract notice.

Answer (score 0):

You could just say "self-promoting." "That annoying, self-promoting behavior drives me nuts."

Answer (score 0):

'Brag blatantly' is something that you could use to depict such a self-promoting behavior. Besides, you could use the idiom 'blowing one's own trumpet' too.